# JSON serialisation in AFNewtorking is failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios7, afnetworking

I am trying to perform GET requests that returns JSON string from a web-service using AFNetworking but I am receiving the following error from AFNetworking 1.3.3

**@"JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."**

and here is my JSON which is a valid JSON string , I used many online validators to make sure

**"{\"ErrorCode\":0,\"VerCode\":\"8595\"}"**

**AFNetworking Code that is not working**

```
NSString *urlString = [BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:paramseters];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                        path:urlString
                                                  parameters:nil];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                    NSDictionary *jsonDic = (NSDictionary *)JSON;

                                                    success(jsonDic);

                                                }
                                                failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

                                                    CPError *cpError = [CPError CPErrorWithErrorCode:error.code errorDesc:error.localizedDescription];

                                                    failure(cpError);

                                                }];
[operation start];
```

I was able to parse the JSON into NSDictionary using the below code but I want to be able to use AFNetworking in order to make use of it's built in features , is there a way to make AFNetworking understands my JSON string ?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://103.1.173.60/ims-mobile-wcf/MobileWCF.svc/AddUpdateMobileClient/123123/443da4444/1/1"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:120];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *JSONString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSDictionary *JSONDictionary =
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error: &error];


}];
```

Comment: Post the failing code, not different code that works. Check for the requirements for JSON with AFNetworking.

Comment: Personally I would break out [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) and insure what is being sent and what is being returned. (free trial).

Comment: @Zaph I posted the code that works to point out that the issue is not with the server response and is in fact with AFNetworking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = ...
    operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
    [operation start];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I got a success from AFNetowrking but the object returned was a JSON string not an NSDictionry so I had to parse the string into NSDictionry using                                                         NSDictionary *JSONDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

Comment: I think that issue has your server.
If response of AFNetworking with default configs not return success, then I guess that the server not return application/json content type.
So It will be better to ask to your server developer to check that.

Comment: The downvote is because all your hack does is allow him to read the quoted JSON as an NSString.  It doesn't result in parsed JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab and say the reason is that the response string appears to be in quotes, if this is the case then the error is very clear - the Fragments option is not set.  Do a a global search for "JSONReadingOptions" and you'll find the place in AFNetworking where the response is serialized into a foundation object (in version 1.3 it's AFJsonRequestOperation line 79, it looks like your using 2.0) is basically exactly what you are doing manually.  If you do as arturdev suggests and set the reading options to be NSJSONReadingAllowFragments it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *JSONString = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

NSDictionary *JSONDictionary =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];
```

`JSONObjectWithData:` does not return an `NSString`, it returns an object: `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`, in your case a `NSDictionary`
Just use:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```